# Spring boot does not start in Tomcat instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat8

I have a small web application that only contains some scheduled task. When I deploy this app on a Tomcat instance nothing happens. No logs are generated, scheduling does not work. The only log I found of the application is:

```
31-Aug-2018 11:05:06.120 INFO [http-nio-80-exec-107] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
```

I have following annotations to the application class (where main is in):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(InfluxProperties.class)
@EnableScheduling
```

The class where the scheduled task is in looks like:

```
@Component
public class MQMonitorTask {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MQMonitorTask.class);

    /**
     * Get the MQ depth of all the queues and send it to Influx
     */
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
    public void getMQData() {
        logger.info("test");
        //Custom code here
    }
}
```

Pom file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.atlascopco</groupId>
    <artifactId>PTITMonitorIntegrator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <name>PTITMonitorIntegrator</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>mq</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>mq.allclient</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>msg.client.commonservices.wmq</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.influxdb/influxdb-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.influxdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>influxdb-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>Spring boot application that will query for information for PT-IT Monitor system</description>
</project>
```

Can someone help me to find this issue? When I create a `jar` file instead of a `war` file and run it with `java -jar file.jar` it just startup and works without any issue. But it is a requirement to run in on a Tomcat server.

Comment: As I can see you do not use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` like here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-include-maven-plugin

Comment: I don&#39;t think that `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` should be `provided`.

Comment: None of the above two comments does work in our situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at this spring-boot documentation [Create a Deployable War File](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)?

Does your application class extend SpringBootServletInitializer ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change 
**jar** 
to 
**war** in pom.xml